# jQuery vs. prototypeJS; size children

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, children

I currently work on a magento webshop, which loads PrototypeJS as framework.

However i need jQuery at some point to do some custom stuff.

jQuery is loaded after prototype and runs in noConflict mode.

Now, here's my demo HTML:

```
<div id="someID">
<div>child</div>
<div>child</div>
<div>child</div>
</div>
```

An external JS file is loaded and contains the following;

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    alert($j('#someID').children().length);
});
```

My alert shows '1' (on any selector) where 3 is expected.

Weird?!

Comment: What does $j('#someID').children().each(function(i, child) {alert('!')}); do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the solution:
Script.aculo.us was outdated, i updated to the latest version and everything is just fine :)

See:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how-to/how_to_use_jquery_1.2.6_lastest_with_prototype

Answer (score 0):

Using only that code alone in a test file, I get the proper value.  Is it possible that the other elements are being removed from or rearranged in the DOM using some other code?

Comment: I did some debugging;
As soon as scriptaculous/effects.js gets loaded my alert shows '1', otherwise '3'